# Removing part of an image and merging the remainder parts using python

Tags: python

I would like to know how I can remove the gray flags and merges the remainder image as shows in picture below. The gray flags have constant RGB(192,192,192).

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I have been trying using mask in opencv and also some tries in scikit image but all have been a mess. Any help is really appreciate I’m new with this stuff.

Comment: can you provide the original image without the border / text?

Comment: Thanks for your reply , the original image is already uploaded. Again, Thank you very much

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that these were two links... Would you mind accepting and upvoting my answer if it solved your problem? Generally, this is to show others that the question has been solved and a nice gesture to the one who took the time to work on your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using scikit image and numpy:

```
In [1]: from skimage import io

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [4]: image = io.imread("input.png")

In [5]: search_line = image[300]  # the line we're going to use for detecting gray areas

In [6]: v = 192  # target value
   ...: e = 30   # allowed epsilon
   ...: include = []
   ...: start = 0
   ...: for i, px in enumerate(search_line):
   ...:     is_gray = np.all((px[:3] > (v-e)) & (px[:3] < (v+e)))
   ...:     if is_gray and start is not None:
   ...:         include.append((start, i))
   ...:         start = None
   ...:     elif not is_gray and start is None:
   ...:         start = i
   ...: if start is not None:
   ...:     include.append((start, len(search_line)))
   ...:

In [7]: slices = [image[:, start:end] for start, end in include]  # relevant image parts

In [8]: plt.imshow(np.concatenate(slices, 1))  # concatenate image parts and show them
Out[8]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x167c523f7f0>

In [9]: plt.show()
```

#### Output

Using the image you provided, the code above produces the following image:

[image]

You can play around with the `e` parameter to get rid of the rest of the grey lines, but this really depends on your original image.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, in first instance the code leaves some gray spots. It was solved running it at the top, middle and lower part of the image (Lines 0, 250 and 500). I played around with epsilon but I got the same image every time. Anyway your code is a great help. Many Thanks.

Comment: I used the other image first, and because that one is compressed, the grey lines aren't exactly (192, 192, 192). I introduced `e` (epsilon) to allow small variations. If it doesn't make a difference in your original image, just ignore it.

Comment: Would you mind accepting and upvoting my answer if it solved your problem? Generally, this is to show others that the question has been solved and a nice gesture to the one who took the time to work on your problem. That's the up arrow and check mark left of this answer.

Comment: Hi Felix, I accepted your answer, it was really helpful. But I cannot upvoting it. I got a message saying I have not privileges. I will try again. Thanks for your answer.